# how to build a maven project with maestrodev / puppet-maven?

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, vagrant, puppet

I have used the maestrodev maven plugin to install maven on ubuntu.

I've checked out a project using the vcsrepo plugin, after which I have been using `exec` to build the project:

```
exec { "build_myproj":
   cwd     => "/myproj",
   command => "mvn clean install eclipse:eclipse",
   path    => "/usr/local/bin/:/usr/bin:/bin/",
   user    => vagrant
}
```

I was wondering if there was a better way to build the project? I have been through the [maven-plugin documentation](https://github.com/maestrodev/puppet-maven), but couldn't see anything relevant there.

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks fine to me, although you need to make sure it runs after maven is installed.